# UIGraphicsImageRenderer: pngData for grayscale image

Tags: ios, uiimage, uikit, core-graphics, color-space

I have enjoyed using the newer APIs from `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` introduced since iOS 10, but now I'm wondering if it's possible at all to get a grayscale `Data` from its `pngData` method.

Say I have an input image called "mask.png", a grayscale image. I have verified that it loads up as grayscale by looking at `UIImage`'s underlying colorspace. The older API `UIImagePNGRepresentation` seems to be able to detect the colorspace and encode its returned `Data` properly. However, the `pngData` function introduced since iOS 10 seems to convert my `Data` to RGB colorspace.

```
extension UIImage {
    public func pngData_olderAPI() -> Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
    }

    public func pngData() -> Data {
        let renderedSize = CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: renderedSize, format: UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat())
        return renderer.pngData { (rendererContext) in
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: renderedSize.width, height: renderedSize.height)
            self.draw(in: rect)
        }
    }
}

let mask = UIImage(named: "mask.png")
print(mask?.cgImage?.colorSpace.debugDescription)

let data = mask?.pngData_olderAPI()
let unwrappedMask = UIImage(data: data!)
print(unwrappedMask?.cgImage?.colorSpace.debugDescription)

let data2 = mask?.pngData()
let unwrappedMask2 = UIImage(data: data2!)
print(unwrappedMask2?.cgImage?.colorSpace.debugDescription)
```

Here's the (simplified) output:

```
...kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Dot Gain 20%))")
...kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Dot Gain 20%))")
...kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1))")
```

I don't see how I can set the colorspace in the newer API. Is it possible to save a grayscale image with the new API?

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 12, `UIGraphicsImageRender` will automatically select the right color space based on the drawing performed. In my case, it automatically created the image with the grayscale color space.

```
<CGColorSpace 0x280d869a0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile)
```

This was explained in the [iOS Memory Deep Dive](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018-416/?time=1261) session at WWDC 2018.

There isn't a way to manually specify a color space with this API. Related to this however, you can set the `preferredRange` on `UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat`, but there's not an option for preferring monochrome.